# as.numeric/as.integer not working in R

Tags: r, integer, warnings, numeric

I'm new to R and trying to do a simple ANOVA. I created a data frame:

```
MeanTable <- data.frame(Age=c("2","2","2","4","4","4","6","6","6"), 
   Yield=c("12.812","15.17","13.868","24.456","23.444","25.312",
         "21.146","21.63","21.84"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And then tried to do an ANOVA, but I got this warning message:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
>     argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
>   2: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
>     argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
>   3: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
>     argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

So I assume that means I'm meant to use as.numeric to convert the values from factors into numbers. So I did this:

```
as.numeric(MeanTable$Age)
is.numeric(MeanTable$Age)
```

But got `FALSE`. What am I doing wrong? Or is my issue something else entirely?

Comment: why are you putting quotes around everything? or is that how the data come to you? To brute-force it, you can add `MeanTable[] <- lapply(MeanTable, type.convert)` but this can be avoided by not doing the quotes

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the response value to numeric *within* the data frame.

```
MeanTable <- data.frame(Age=c("2","2","2","4","4","4","6","6","6"), 
   Yield=c("12.812","15.17","13.868","24.456","23.444","25.312",
         "21.146","21.63","21.84"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

MeanTable$Yield <- as.numeric(MeanTable$Yield)
lm(Yield~Age,data=MeanTable)
```

As @rawr points out it would be easier if your variables were numeric to begin with.  However, be careful: if you make `Age` numeric rather than categorical you will be fitting a regression model rather than a 1-way ANOVA.